# Show that the following equation has got exactly one solution for each $C>0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

> Show that the equation $$C=\left ( 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2} \right)*e^{-x}$$
>
> has got exactly one solution for each $C>0$.

Alright so I did it like that but not sure if it's correct:

$0<\left ( 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2} \right)*e^{-x}$ |: $e^{-x}$

$0<\left ( 1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^{2} \right)$ | *$2$

$0<\left ( 2+2x+x^{2} \right)$

$0<x^{2}+2x+2$

$0 < \left ( x+1 \right)^{2}+1$

$0 < x+1+\sqrt{1}$

$x > -2$

To be honest, I'm not sure if my preparation is correct at all. "show(...) exactly one solution for each $C>0$" confusing me.

*Again, this is no homework, only practice for me.
If anyone wants I can upload the pdf (example for our exam) here.*

Comment: What happened to $C$? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I set $0$ for it. Everything wrong? :(

Comment: Yes, it's all wrong. Is this a Calculus problem? Do you know what a derivative is?

Comment: Yes I know what a derivative is.

Comment: Hint: Work out the derivative and show that it is negative.

Comment: But how do you know I have to use derivative? I'd never thought of needing that, probably because I understood the task wrong : /

Comment: If there is exactly one solution $x$ for all $C$ for an equation $f(x) = C$, the function $f$ must be either decreasing or increasing. And that can be checked with the derivative.

Comment: I saw the problem and thought "hmm, well we want to show that $f$ is monotone then this problem becomes pretty straightforward", drawing a rough graph also helps my intuition. Then: "this is a pretty straightforward function and I know that $e^x$ has nice derivatives, let me try differentiating...". Essentially, for nice continuous functions over the reals, derivatives are a good tool for investigating monotonocity.

Comment: To help intuit Hans's claim, draw graphs. Look at the graph of a quadratic, can you see why a horizontal line will cut the quadratic in two places because it goes down and then back up again? Look at the graph of $x^3$. can you see how a horizontal line will only cut the graph once because the graph starts out in the bottom left and goes up and up and up without any curving back downwards? Then, can you see the link with the graph only going up or down with the derivative? Keep in mind that the derivative is the (instantenous) gradient, so if the gradient is always positive, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g(x)$ is a differentiable function, the derivative of $g(x)e^{-x}$ is given by $\left(g'(x)-g(x)\right)e^{-x}$.
If $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$ we have that $g'(x)-g(x)$ is a monomial and an even function, hence $f(x)=g(x)e^{-x}$ has a unique stationary point at the origin and is a decreasing function.
Since $\lim_{x\to +\infty}g(x)e^{-x}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)e^{-x}=+\infty$, we have that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is a bijective function.

Here it is how our functions behave in a neighbourhood of the origin, for $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$:

$\hspace{1in}$[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = e^{-x} (1 + x + x^2/2)$ then $$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2e^{-x}$$ via the product rule, this shows that (since $x^2$ and $e^{-x}$ are non-negative for all real $x$) that $f'(x) \leq 0 $ and so $f$ is a decreasing function. It is obviously continuous and tends to (positive) infinity as $x \to -\infty$ and tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: You again, thank you very much!